# Can "about" and "around" be used interchangeably in some cases?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Example:

> He paced about/around the room.

Can those words be used interchangeably? If that's the case, which one is more common?

Comment: You cannot use *around* in this case. It is a fixed expression. I'd say you can only use them interchangeably in a minority of cases, probably mainly when you're talking about physically standing or going around/about something. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+around+their+lives%2Cgo+about+their+lives&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20about%20their%20lives%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Cerberus how about this new example?

Comment: Sounds good to me! You can use either there. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paced%20about%20the%20room%2Cpaced%20around%20the%20room&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpaced%20about%20the%20room%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpaced%20around%20the%20room%3B%2Cc0

Comment: They can be used interchangeably for estimation: He was about 30. He was around 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, **yes**, one can both pace *about* and *around* a room.  Both are correct, and both mean the same thing - to walk randomly in the room or possibly along the periphery.

*Around* doesn't always mean on the outside circumference of something.  Two relevant definitions from the OED:

> About (adv):  5. In U.S.: = about adv. a. Here and there with no fixed direction; all about, at random; as in ‘to travel around,’ ‘to fool around’.
>
> About (prep): 4. U.S. (a) Hither and thither over, at random through, about; as in ‘to travel around the country’. (b) Of time, amount, etc.: about, sometime near.

In most cases, however, *about* is **not** interchangeable with *around*.

Answer (score 0):

Often, the preposition *around* is used as shorthand for *around various physical spaces inside the confines of*; while this is not technically correct English, the practice has certainly become accepted via folk etymology, that is, through evolution of language as it is used by laypeople over time.

One cannot, technically, *pace around the room* while being inside of the room; the very abstraction implied by *around* involves space specifically *adjacent to but strictly not including* (the object of the prepositional phrase). One who *paces around the room* technically walks near the room but not inside of it.

In contrast, the preposition *about* implies much more flexible criteria describing the relationship of the verb-implied-action to the object of the prepositional phrase. A common word preceding *about* is the verb *to talk*, for example, and someone who *talks about the room* is most likely talking such that the content of their words, or their message, is directly related to the room and its properties as a noun-thing.

It should be pointed out, however, that *to talk about the room* may also be inferred such as to conjure the image of someone talking, on an unspecified subject, while physically occupying various spaces inside the room.

Prepositions are probably more prone to the confusions associated with folk-etymological development than would be prone any other part of speech. This might be, in part, because prepositions are essentially pseudo-mathematical in nature, in the sense that they are used to compare, contrast, and ultimately triangulate between two or more ideas; that is, they are used to define one thing by means of/relativity to another thing.

Such insertion of very logical operation into language is recipe for confusion.

Observing this basic pattern, and following it successfully to its logical conclusion, that almost all stated ideas involving preposition-phrases can be described in at least two different manners, I find it silly to suggest that any particular preposition is correct.

And unless you can tell me right now whether I just *spoke around prepositions* or *spoke about prepositions* and back up your answer with a definitive unarguable proof, it would seem you might be wise to consider adopting a similar attitude towards prepositions in the English language.

Comment: Native speakers of English are "laypeople"? Also, folk etymology specifically relates to borrowed words. It does not refer to language change in general. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_etymology

Comment: see the very first line of the article you've cited; it is a disambiguation link to another article that happens to be titled "false etymology" on wikipedia. i apologize that my ironic usage of "folk etymology" and "layperson" and several other obvious falsely-evolved nouns is not appreciated here; my assumptions about (around?) language forums may be incorrect.

Comment: My objection was to the notion that the typical usage of *around* (or the typical usage of anything) is "not technically correct". But that's not a battle for SE comment threads. Just two notes on your terminology: nothing you have discussed is etymology (word origins), and *about* and *around* are examples of prepositions, not pronouns.

Comment: thank you kindly for pointing out my continued use of "pronoun" where i meant "preposition" - there was nothing intentional or artistic about that, simply a mistake - i will make that change right away.

Comment: i seem to be holding onto the idea that i'm correct to describe the integration of preposition phrases in a manner similar to slang as being etymology, and that the class of etymology would be folk as is the case with most slang or introduction of non-intentional new words &/or new uses for existing words. if i am wrong could you explain why, and try to include what field of study would be more appropriate to mention here?

Comment: You're talking about the evolution of syntax, whereas etymology would be concerned with the word itself -- its pronunciation, meaning, source language, etc. You could argue that how a word is used syntactically could be included, but IMO that is just more than is usually meant by the word "etymology". And even if so, folk/false etymology is not the acceptance of nonstandard constructions or vocabulary, but rather popular, incorrect explanations of how those words came to be.

Comment: ah, very good, i'm able now to see your position as being potentially as valid and possibly more-so than my own, thank you for taking the time to explain in a courteous manner, i truly admire civility in such forums as this. i will use the leads you've provided to research the relevant topics then adjust &/or correct my understanding.